# How to sort decimals by Odd/Even (Python)

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
def mrdot2(v):
  for x in v:
    if x % 2 == 0:
      print("Even")
    elif x % 2 == 1:
      print("Odd")

mrdot2([2,4,6,23,68,5,3,2.4,29,4877.5423,8139,48.3,89.5,10.3,-7,-8])
```

And everything works as usual (prints "Even" with even numbers and "Odd" with odd numbers) but it doesn't work with the decimals (it just prints nothing). It should print "Even" if the number ends with 0, 2, 4 , 6,  or 8 and "Odd" if the number ends with 1, 3, 5, 7, or 9. Is there a way I could fix this?

Comment: What does it even *mean* for a decimal (floating point value) to be either even or odd? There is no standard meaning of those predicates for non-integer values. Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can round the decimals to their integer counterpart using round().

Comment: try, ``int(x % 2) == 1``

Comment: Is `48.3` even? Is it odd? Why?

Comment: It is not clear... If I read the example you want to determine and print if each number of the list is even, odd (o neither in the case of decimal numbers)...

Comment: To add to what @KarlKnechtel said. If you say that 48.3 is even since it truncates to an even integer, that is very straightforward and the decimal part isn't even relevant for what you are trying to do. On the other hand, if you say that it is odd since 48.3 ends in 3, then there is a problem. When you enter the literal `48.3`, it is converted to a float for which the fractional part is *not* 3/10 (that can't be represented in base 2 exactly). This would make your even/odd classification an artifact of how you are *formatting* the numbers rather than a property of the numbers themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can determine if a number is even, odd or neither and print. Decimal numbers (decimal part different to 0) are not even or odd. Note that for example 5.0 = 5 in this special case. Maybe the following code can help you.

```
def function(myList):
    for number in myList:
        if number % 2 == 0 and number - int(number) == 0:
            print("Even")
        elif number % 2 != 0 and number - int(number) == 0:
            print("Odd")
        else:
            print("Neither odd nor even")
            
function([2, 4, 6, 23, 68, 5, 3, 2.4, 29, 4877.5423, 8139, 48.3, 89.5, 10.3, -7, -8, 4.0, 7.0])
```

The output is the following:

```
Even
Even
Even
Odd
Even
Odd
Odd
Neither odd nor even
Odd
Neither odd nor even
Odd
Neither odd nor even
Neither odd nor even
Neither odd nor even
Odd
Even
Even
Odd
```

Comment: Checking for an integer value is always easy using isinstance(x, int).

Comment: You can simplify this code by just writing `if x % 2 == 0:` and `if x % 2 == 1`, that already takes care of making sure `x` was actually an integer, or a floating point number with a zero decimal.

Answer (score 0):

The even/odd classification refers only to integers. So decimals cannot be even or odd.

```
4877.5423
```

This is not odd or even due to the above mentioned reason

If the number is odd, it must have a remainder of 1 after dividing by two

but, if you wan't your code to say that its odd ( even though its wrong )

```
def mrdot2(v):
  for x in v:
    if x % 2 == 0:
      print("Even")
    elif x % 2 <= 1:
      print("Odd")

mrdot2([2,4,6,23,68,5,3,2.4,29,4877.5423,8139,48.3,89.5,10.3,-7,-8])
```

and if you run the code as i say, it will give a output like this

```
Even
Even
Even
Odd
Even
Odd
Odd
Odd
Odd
Odd
Odd
Odd
Odd
Odd
Odd
Even
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because numbers like **4877.5423** in your list are of float type.
4877.5423 % 2 = 1.5423000000000684 (which is neither 0 nor 1)
Cases like these are not going in your "if" and "elif" statements and are not getting printed.